# Cuda opengl interop and cudaGraphicsGLRegisterImage causes error

Tags: opengl, cuda

I am trying to do some cross card communication with cuda running on my K20 and opengl running on my quadro but I seem to be unable to register the texture I want to use with cuda.

My code looks something like this

```
glGenTextures(1, &texId);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texId);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, textureSize, textureSize, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0); 
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

checkGLError();  // Passes 


// This will cause an Access Violation when run from visual studio 10 debugger 
cudaGraphicsGLRegisterImage(&texRes, texId, GL_TEXTURE_2D,cudaGraphicsRegisterFlagsNone);

// If ran with out debugger, cudaGetErrorString() will spit out "invalid argument"
checkCudaError();
```

cudaGraphicsGLRegisterImage causes an Access Violation when run from visual studio 10 debugger

but...

If ran with out debugger, cudaGetErrorString() will spit out "invalid argument"

I am not sure what the problem could be and it is made more confusing by the different error messages.

Comment: Have you taken a look at OpenGL interop demos that come with CUDA SDK

Comment: Yes but none that I could find used cudaGraphicsGLRegisterImage.

Comment: I think gaussian blur demo uses this method to map OpenGL texture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I seem to have figured out what was wrong I changed the line...

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, textureSize, textureSize, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
```

to...

```
glTexImage2D (GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8, textureSize, textureSize, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
```

I am not sure why cuda has a problem with GL_RGBA but that seems to be the case.